# transformation list to str and print it using join f(x)

Tags: python

I want to do this exercise :

**Write a python programme that take a string from user , reverse it and then print it .**

I tried some code but it didn't work :

```
a = str(input("your str :"))
x = []
for i in a :
   x.append(i)
x = x.reverse()
b = " ".join(x)
print(b)
```

guys that code `b = " ".join(x)` : is that change from a list to str .

look when I used it in IDLE

```
>>> a = ["khalid" ,"safi", "is", "programer"]
>>> b = " ".join(a)
>>> b
'khalid safi is programer'
>>> print(b)
khalid safi is programer
```

Comment: what did you get as output when you printed

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\chap8ex2.py", line 6, in <module>
    b = " ".join(x)
TypeError: can only join an iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reverse() works inplace,  it means that you don't need
x = x.reverse()

this will work:

```
a = str(input("your str :"))
x=[]
for i in a:
   x.append(i)
x.reverse()
b = " ".join(x)
print(b)
```

But it still not good way to reverse string

Comment: use this: b = "".join(x)

Comment: Between "" you can place string that will be separate (it maybe " ", ";" or something else)

Comment: @khalidsafi if it worked accept his answer that is click the tick button to his answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to convert to a list. Just use `string[::-1]`

Or, if you just want to reverse the words, do this:

```
a = str(input("your str :"))
x=a.split()[::-1]
print(" ".join(x))
```

Comment: i know this method but i want use my method that use join

Comment: @khalidsafi provide this info in the question

Comment: is in the exe see you have to use join f(x)

Comment: Edited my answer to what I think is what you were asking

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
a[::-1]
```

To reverse the string

Your method failed due this line

```
x = x.reverse()
```

list.reverse() acts on the list and changes the list that is you do not need to assign it to another list

Since you assigned it **x** the value returned by reverse is None since it does not provide any return value so **None** is saved in x .

ANd you applied `"".join(x) on a None object` so it resulted in error

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x = str(input("your str :")).split()
x = x.reverse()
b = " ".join(x)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use slicing to reverse the list of words..

If you are a python2.* user use this:

```
print " ".join(raw_input("plz enter str : ").split(" ")[::-1])
```

if you are a python3 user use this:

```
print(str.join(" ", input("plz enter str : ").split(" ")[::-1]))
```